# How to select TextBox Using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How to select TextBox Using VBA. I want to make changes for those Textboxes which i have selected manually to change their font, backcolor.

```
Set s = ws.Shapes("").Selected Shape


Sub TextBox()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Shape

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set s = ws.Shapes("TextBox 7") ' Here i want to add one thing that is it should work for selected textbox manually

s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
s.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
s.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be simplified by using the
[ShapeRange property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shaperange)
of the Selection object that returns all the shapes in the selection.

The following example sets the fill foreground color for all the shapes in the selection in window one, assuming that there's at least one shape in the selection.

```
Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 255)
```

In your code, you could just set:

```
Set s = Windows(1).Selection.ShapeRange
```

Comment: Thank you its working perfect.